# Which is the best way to store a variable number of variables?

Tags: c++

If I have a `for` loop that reads from a data file and each time I have a varible number of variables, say `jet1_emfr, jet2_emfr, ...`, if `N` is the number of these variables, I used something like

```
vector<double> jet_emfr;
osstringstream oss;

for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ){
oss << "jet" << i << "_emfr";
jet_emf.push_back(oss.str());
oss.str("");
}
```

to store them, is it the best way? And What if I want to associate the name of the variable to its value, I mean, I created a `map`

```
map<string,TLorentzVector> map_jets;

map_jets["jet1"] = jet1_mom;
map_jets["jet2"] = jet2_mom;
map_jets["jet3"] = jet3_mom;
...
```

and used a `vector<pair<string,double> > jets_pt` to associate `jet1` to a value given by `jet1_mom.Pt()`, now I need to impose a condition that whenever `jet_emfr[i] < 0.4` i have to erase (or not store) the value of the corresponding `jet?_mom.Pt()` in (from) `jets_pt`.

Comment: Why don't you just use an array (or vector) rather than lots of separate variables?

Comment: I don't see any "reading" in your code.

Comment: I use them to make selection of the events based on the value of differents methods applied on `jet1_mom`, and, as I'm not a good programmer, I found this way to accomplish my tasks, it's not possibly the best.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, assume that the data is read and those variables are taken in this way: `jet?_emfr->GetValue()`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the data structures you used. 
Using a std::vector to hold your double values is definitely a good way to go. 
And using an std::map to associate your data with a string is also a good way to store the association.

Comment: Ok, I was asking because I'm learning c++ and wandering if what I have done could also be done in a more efficient/better way :-)

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is to have dynamic variables, and being capable of "linking" an "id" to a "value"... I think you're best off with using an `undordered_map` / `hash_map`. As the name implies those aren't "sorted/ordered". - So looking up (and inserting etc) is done in O(1) time.

Especially when the numbers get really big the undordered map might become faster than a normal map.

Otherwise, a normal map sounds good. Depending on your needs you should use a string, or maybe an enum for key.

Comment: I'm asked to chose, for examlpe, the greatest two values between all `jet?_mom.Pt()`, thus I thought to sort the vector of pairs in increasing order and always pick up the first two elements so i think I can also take a look at `unordered_map` / `hash_map`. Thanks for pointing out :-)